# Why does there OnFinalMessage never be called in ATL?

Tags: atl, assert

I am using ATL do build my software. I create a main frame window which contain serviral childen windows. the one of the childen windows contain some chinden windows also.

Now, my app will alway get the failed of assert:

```
    virtual ~CWindowImplRoot()
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        if(m_hWnd != NULL)  // should be cleared in WindowProc
        {
            ATLTRACE(atlTraceWindowing, 0, _T("ERROR - Object deleted before window was destroyed\n"));
            ATLASSERT(FALSE);
        }
#endif //_DEBUG
    }
```

I defined WM_NCDESTROY handler for any window and set bHanded=FALSE, the code can arrived there.

Anymore, I add OnFinalMessage override function. unfortunatelly, no all of the functions can be called. Actually, the top-level window's OnFinalMessage will be called, the middle-level windows' OnFinalMessage may not be called, the bottom-level windows' OnFinalMessage will never be called.

I oberve the source code of ATL:

```
template <class TBase, class TWinTraits>
LRESULT CALLBACK CWindowImplBaseT< TBase, TWinTraits >::WindowProc(
    _In_ HWND hWnd,
    _In_ UINT uMsg,
    _In_ WPARAM wParam,
    _In_ LPARAM lParam)
{
    CWindowImplBaseT< TBase, TWinTraits >* pThis = (CWindowImplBaseT< TBase, TWinTraits >*)hWnd;
    // set a ptr to this message and save the old value
    _ATL_MSG msg(pThis->m_hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    const _ATL_MSG* pOldMsg = pThis->m_pCurrentMsg;
    pThis->m_pCurrentMsg = &msg;
    // pass to the message map to process
    LRESULT lRes = 0;
    BOOL bRet = pThis->ProcessWindowMessage(pThis->m_hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam, lRes, 0);
    // restore saved value for the current message
    ATLASSERT(pThis->m_pCurrentMsg == &msg);

    // do the default processing if message was not handled
    if(!bRet)
    {
        if(uMsg != WM_NCDESTROY)
            lRes = pThis->DefWindowProc(uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        else
        {
            // unsubclass, if needed
            LONG_PTR pfnWndProc = ::GetWindowLongPtr(pThis->m_hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC);
            lRes = pThis->DefWindowProc(uMsg, wParam, lParam);
            if(pThis->m_pfnSuperWindowProc != ::DefWindowProc && ::GetWindowLongPtr(pThis->m_hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC) == pfnWndProc)
                ::SetWindowLongPtr(pThis->m_hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)pThis->m_pfnSuperWindowProc);
            // mark window as destryed
            pThis->m_dwState |= WINSTATE_DESTROYED;
        }
    }
    if((pThis->m_dwState & WINSTATE_DESTROYED) && pOldMsg== NULL)
    {
        // clear out window handle
        HWND hWndThis = pThis->m_hWnd;
        pThis->m_hWnd = NULL;
        pThis->m_dwState &= ~WINSTATE_DESTROYED;
        // clean up after window is destroyed
        pThis->m_pCurrentMsg = pOldMsg;
        pThis->OnFinalMessage(hWndThis);
    }else {
        pThis->m_pCurrentMsg = pOldMsg;
    }
    return lRes;
}
```

In above code, the purpose of the variable "pOldMsg" is to indicate the call stack level. if "pOldMsg" not equal to NULL, it's means that the call stack is not returned. when it's NULL, means the the call stack is outermost level, this moment we can call OnFinalMessage function now.

In my case, it's seems that sometimes "pOldMsg" will never equal to NULL.

chat:

```
   MainFrame                         V
     |----- ViewDevices              V
     |----- ViewContainer            X
              |----- ViewBooks       X
              |----- ViewFiles       V
```

After testing it for many times, I find that, if I didn't add any content to the ViewBooks(ListView) window, every things is OK. Once I add just a line, this issue will repro. I don't know whether the sending message by crossing thread cause the issue.

Can anybody give me some suggestions?

Comment: The problem might be that your destructors are called *before* `WM_NCDESTROY` is sent and `OnFinalMessage` is to be called.

Comment: Thanks Roman R. I find the issue occurs the function 
LRESULT CViewBooks::OniDeviceNotify(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
{
    bHandled = FALSE;
    iDevice *device = (iDevice *) lParam;
    BOOL isConnect = (BOOL) wParam;
    if (m_node) {
        if (m_node->device == device) {
            if (FALSE == isConnect) {
                // clear up all contents and tasks.
                DeleteAllItems();
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

Comment: If i remove the function, anything is OK. Maybe something is wrong in this function. I will obverse it again.